# how to add dinamically components with data, on objects list with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, components

I have a component list, in this case is a MUI chips, which has some props (label, callback) and I need to add them to my list when onClick event is triggered.
The chip is going to have a label, which is a name selected from a dropdown menu.

I found quite difficult to have a unique chip with the name selected.

[image]

```
//my components list
const [chipList, setChip] = useState([{ chip: "" }]);
    
const addNewCategory = () => {
  if (chipList.length < 5) {
    setChip([...chipList, { chip: "" }]); 
  }
};
      
//my map to render the component
{chipList.map((widget, index) => (
  <CategoryChip key={index} label={subCategory} onDelete={() => handleDelete(index)} />
))}
```

I am quite sure I have to pass the label inside my `useState([{ chip: "" }])` and **yes I know,** for the moment my chips has all same name because of the `label` attribute

Comment: What do you mean by "I found quite difficult to have a unique chip with the name selected."?? Do you want a specific chip to be selected as in the CSS changes? Or are you talking when you click on the "x" button, knowing which chip you clicked?

Comment: What I meant is, to select an option from the select dropdown and then show the chip with the selected option name on it, as you can see on the pic, I selected "F1"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to map() your chipList if your intent is to only show one. The one that is selected.

I'm assuming your subCategory state or prop is the chip info that you chose from the dropdown.
You can use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to show CategoryChip related with that choice.

```
export default YourComponent = () => {
  const [chipList, setChip] = useState([{ chip: "" }]);
  
  const addNewCategory = () => {
    if (chipList.length < 5) {
      setChip([...chipList, { chip: "" }]); 
    }
  };

  ...

  const renderSelectedChip = () => {
    const foundChipIndex = chipList.findIndex(el => el.chip === subCategory);
    
    // I checked for subCategory just to make sure that empty string wasn't a selectable option, but you can remove it if you want 
    if (!subCategory || foundChipIndex === -1) {
      return <></>;
    }

    return <CategoryChip label={subCategory} onDelete={() => handleDelete(foundChipIndex)} />
))} />
  }

  return (
    <>
      ...
      {renderSelectedChip()}
    </>
  ) 
}
```